# Get a NSString encrypted from an original NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, encryption

I found a lot of subjects about encryption and AES/DES but I didn't found a way to get a NSString encrypted from an original NSString. Is there a way to have a NSString instead of getting NSData ?

I want to use my NSString encrypted in order to create an URL.
I want to transform something like : `http://test.fr/143` in something like `http://test.fr/AydgzeifgzZEH239c2390304kdjlad` and have the possibility to decrypt this in order to get my 143 string again.

Comment: Google... hundreds of answers are there... and never expect to get 100% of your solution.

Comment: @Anoop : I found a lot of answers on Google and I test many of those in order to have my solution but it didn't work, that's why I ask my question here..

Comment: @pbibergal : It seems to be really cool ! But is there a way to do this with an AES or DES encryption ? If no, can you post your comment as an answer please (in order I accept it) ?

Comment: @pbibergal : Besides, is Base64 a secure method to encrypt/decrypt datas ?

Comment: @Seb No he shouldn't have suggested Base64, it is an encoding, not an encryption.

Comment: Ok, so I still not have my answer.. :/ Thank you for the precision @0x7fffffff ! If you have a suggestion for my question, do not hesitate :)

Comment: @Seb I'm sorry but I don't. I'm completely under qualified to give you security advice. I just know enough to know that Base64 isn't the way to go :)

Comment: @Seb Scratch that, here's a tutorial for AES encryption in Objective-C using the build in CommonCrypto Framework: http://robnapier.net/blog/aes-commoncrypto-564

Comment: @0x7fffffff thank you but it's just explained how to encrypt datas.

Comment: @Seb That's alright, you can convert back and forth between NSString and NSData. There are plenty of resources available on this.

Comment: Anything you can decode is not an encryption.. Anyways you can think of your own pattern and encode it with any encrypt algorithm you'd like.